# How can I update my TOML file if I can't access my website's folder directory?

Tags: xlm, stellar.toml

Currently for my website I'm using Weebly, which is one of those drag and drop no code sites. They don't let you access the websites directories internally, so I am having a hard time creating the necessary URL link required for the TOML file to be read.

I was wondering if I should just create a new website and point to that URL so at least the TOML file can be recognized for my custom coin I created?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did personally: I purchased a domain from IONOS, whipped up a simple site and deployed it on fly.io. I was able to include the stellar.toml fine in my websites /.well-known/ directory. I used https://stellar.sui.li/ to make sure everything was correct.

Instead of buying a new domain you could always do some DNS magic to route your app/site to a domain you own.

And you don't have to deploy on fly.io. Can use AWS, Azure, etc.